# Remote rejected on pushing through gerrit in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, push, gerrit, git-push

I am trying to commit+push my code. I have gerrit installed in eclipse.

1. Team->Reset Commit.
2. I committed my file.
3. Push.

Now it is not pushing the code, as I cannot see my logs in the gdt gitblit.
Instead it is saying 'remote rejected'
[image: Issue snapshot]

Answer (score 1):

Some reasons why a push fails:

1. Missing Change-ID, fix by adding the commit-msg hook. See [commit-msg hook](https://dev.mit.com.sg/r/Documentation/cmd-hook-commit-msg.html)
2. Pushing to branch instead of pushing for review. Fix by pushing to `refs/for/master` or `refs/for/your_branch`
3. No access rights (unlikely), ask admin for rights
4. You rely on a out of date patch set, fix by rebasing your patchset on the latest `origin/master`